# How to change voice features in python without affecting speech/language features?

Tags: python, cnn, svm, data-augmentation, speech-to-text

I am trying to build a CNN model which should be able to identify the language being spoken in an  audio file. I have extracted the MFCC matrix (for 13 coefficients) for each audio file and trained it. The audio files are call recordings. The accuracy is too high over a small data sample. The problem I have now is that in many audio files, there are common voices. I have a suspicion that the model is giving high importance to these voice features instead of features which are important to identify language (i.e. since 1 person speaks in only one language, the model might think the voice features of those files are important for classification - this will make it fail while testing for new voices). How do I manipulate the data such that each audio files has a different voice? (example: changing frequency is one way)

Comment: Try testing your hypothesis, feed new examples from any call you can produce

Comment: Tested it, on new calls its gibing around 72% accuracy (dropped from around 91% before)